# How many payments happened on Monday from payment _date column? The below code giving me zero count

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payment
WHERE(TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'Day')) = 'Monday'
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Date/time functions are quite database specific, so you should add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is using product specific functions.)

Comment: What data is present in the table?  What value does `TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'Day')` produce?

Comment: Seems likely this is Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe I should have said `Possible` :)

Comment: @David To_Char(payment, 'Day')  produces an output of the days: LIKE MONDAY Thursday Wednesday.    Actually, with EXTRACT FUNCTION, I am getting  the output

Comment: BUT with TO_CHAR (payment_date, Day)  the logic seems ok only.

Comment: THIS IS postgresql

Answer (score 7):

`TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'Day')` returns a string padded with spaces (`'Monday   '`).

To suppress the spaces, use the `FM` modifier ("fill mode")

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payment
WHERE (TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'FMDay')) = 'Monday'
```

alternatively be explicit and use `trim()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payment
WHERE (trim(TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'Day'))) = 'Monday'
```

---

However, I would recommend to **not** use locale specific values (on my computer the above would always return 0 as I have a different language setting).

Using numbers e.g. with `extract(isodow from ..)` is much more reliable.

Comment: Using extract with 'dow' keyword is a recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

Use **dow**(day of week).
The day of the week (0 - 6; Sunday is 0) (for timestamp values only)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payment
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM payment_date)= 1;
```

For more details on the **dow** check out the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS day_of_payment 
FROM payment
WHERE TO_CHAR (payment_date,'DAY') = 'MONDAY   '
```

Considering that "blank padded to 9 characters", which means instead of returning 'Monday' it returns 'Monday   ' with extra spaces to fill up at least 9 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Also,

`SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM payment WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM payment_date) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM payment 
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM payment_date) = 1;
```

`DOW()` function: Returns a numeric value (1 to 7) representing the day of the week for a specified date or datetime. Abbreviation for "Day of Week".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM payment

WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM payment_date) = 1;

Comment: explaining the function and mentioning the reference link helps requester to understand your answer properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).